# How to fix "each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter" error in Android java?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I tried to implement a simple RoomDB in an android app which only has 1 table, and Task objects in it, preloaded through the databaseBuilder's callback. When I try to build the app I get the each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter error, but if I hit run the second time it compiles the app, but I can't insert anything into the database, and if I try to query the preloaded task by its id (0) it gives back null.

This is my Task class, which I want to store in the DB:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int taskId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    public Task(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setTaskId(int taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }


    public int getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task object, id: "+taskId;
    }
}
```

And this is my TaskDAO:

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
    List<Task> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskId = (:taskId)")
    Task getTaskById(int taskId);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Task...tasks);

}
```

And this is the database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Task.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract TaskDAO taskDAO();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "tasks.db")
                    .addCallback(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                            super.onCreate(db);
                            new PopulateInitialData(INSTANCE).execute();
                        }
                    }).build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class PopulateInitialData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final TaskDAO taskDAO;

        public PopulateInitialData(AppDatabase database){
            taskDAO = database.taskDAO();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Task task1 = new Task("Task data");

            taskDAO.insertAll(new Task[] {task1});
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the DB and try to query a task:

```
AppDatabase roomDB = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext());
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Task task = roomDB.taskDAO().getTaskById(0)); //task is null
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **insertAll** method expects an array of Task objects (`Task[]`) not a single Task object.

If you want to insert a single Task object then you could add a new insert method into the DAO e.g.

```
@Insert
void insertOneTask(Task task);
```

Alternately use a single element array with the current **insertAll** method.

e.g.

```
taskDAO.insertAll(new Task[]{task1});
```

> but I can't insert anything into the database, and if I try to query
>   the preloaded task by its id (0) it gives back null.

That is because there will never, under normal circumstances, be a task with an id of 0. The first id will be 1.

If you used the following code

```
            List<Task> alltasks = roomDB.taskDAO().getAll();
            for (Task t: alltasks) {
                Log.d("TASKINFO","Task =" + t.getDescription() + " ID = " + t.getTaskId());
            }
```

after/before or instead of `Task task = roomDB.taskDAO().getTaskById(0)); //task is null`

It would show you that the task id is 1.

e.g. `2019-09-29 20:00:20.463 D/TASKINFO: Task =Task data ID = 1`

To explain ROOM will create the table for the Tasks using :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (`taskId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `Description` TEXT)
```

The taskid column, will be an alias of the rowid column and if not supplied a value, or the supplied value is null. It will then auto-generate a value for the rowid and therefore it's alias. The value will be 1 greater than the the higher of the last recorded value or the highest value currently in the database. If there are no such values then the value will be **1**.

If you used

```
Task task = roomDB.taskDAO().getTaskById(1));
```

The the inserted Task would be returned.

Generally you should never make assumptions about the value of an id, rather it should be obtained programatically, typically from a list, but with ROOM you would typically deal with Objects (e.g.the getAll() and the following for loop as above)

## Testing

The code was tested using the following :-

- **Task.java** copied asis and unchanged
- **TaskDAO.java** copied asis and unchanged.
- **AppDatabase.java** copied asis and unchanged.
- **And this is how I call the DB and try to query a task:**

  - Dropped this code into **MainActivity.java**
  - Made roomDB a class variable, (AppDatabase roomDB) just instantiating it in the onCreate method.
  - Also corrected error (extra parenthesis) and
  - Added getAll and loop code from above.

as per :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase roomDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        roomDB = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Task task = roomDB.taskDAO().getTaskById(0); //task is null
                List<Task> alltasks = roomDB.taskDAO().getAll();
                for (Task t: alltasks) {
                    Log.d("TASKINFO","Task =" + t.getDescription() + " ID = " + t.getTaskId());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, I just copied a wrong code by accident, but the each binding... error is still there doesnt matter if i insert an array of tasks or create a new method to insert only one

Comment: @DaGee the answer has been amended to include the cause and resolution for the issue with id 0 returning null (no such task).

Comment: Oh I understand the ids of room, thanks. Yes I know that I should use an Id directly, I just simplifyd my code, I obtain them programatically. But the problem is still here, I made some more testing, and the asynctask in the AppDatabase class never runs (at least a Log.i in the doInBackground never gets called, so the db remains empty)

Comment: I copied and ran your code. The only changes were with the last code snippet. I dropped this into an activitity's onCreate method. Made the roomDB variable a class variable (`AppDatabase roomDB;`), changed `AppDatabase roomDB = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext());` to be `roomDB = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext());` and removed the errant **)** to use `Task task = roomDB.taskDAO().getTaskById(0); //task is null` and added the code above (getAll and loop).

Comment: Thats interesting. Maybe I should invalidate the caches and clear all app data in the emulator

Comment: @DaGee I'd do that. P.S. am adding the code used to the answer.

Comment: Yes, after I invalidated AndroidStudio's cache everything worked fine...
Thank you for your help and testing :)